# How to run a command as administrator on Windows7 from a command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, runas

I need to run `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` remotely = **not manually** on Windows7 as an administrator. More info here [How to use tscon on Windows7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/428975/how-to-use-tscon-on-windows7)

I did my research and

- OPTION 1 - runas

for user **root** (no password) on computer yogurt works

```
C:\>runas /user:yogurt\root cmd
Enter the password for yogurt\root:
Attempting to start cmd as user "yogurt\root" ...
```

for user **administrator** (I thought the the password is blank too) on computer yogurt doesn't work. I am asked for password, hit the enter and

```
C:\>runas /user:yogurt\administrator cmd
Enter the password for yogurt\administrator:
Attempting to start cmd as user "yogurt\administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd
1327: Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwo
rds not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

- OPTION 2 - setting properties of a batch file so it always runs as administrator. The 'privilege level' section is greyed out for me under Compatibility level. So I am not able to tick the check box `Run this program as an administrator`

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're asking, so this may be off base, but run `cmd` elevated, run the command with an administrative user on the remote system?  What's the problem, or was that the answer?

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I need to run `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` as administrator to see if it fixed the original issue I am facing. Read the link in my question for more details. I am already running the command under account that is a member of administrators group. There might be another issues involved as @Chris said in his EDIT. I need to read about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find that the local Administrator account is in fact disabled. Take a look in the Local Users and Groups in Computer Management.

Regardless of that, I wouldn't recommend enabling the account, especially if it really does have a blank password.

Running a program 'as Administrator' (as in on the right-click menu) and doing a `RunAs` Administrator are *not the same thing*:

- Running a program 'as Administrator' means that the program still runs under the context of your user account (i.e. the person invoking the program) but using a modified access token that includes membership of the `Administrators` group. A process started in this way would show as being owned by you in Task Manager.
- Using `RunAs` with the Administrator account *really does* try to invoke the program under the Administrator account. A process started in this way would show as being owned by `Administrator` in the Task Manager.

EDIT: Although the above is relevant, I think the real problem might be to do with something called [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) which started with Windows Vista/Server 2008.

Comment: If I run `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` on Windows XP I can then run automation testing. On Windows7 I get error when running the test. I want to try if running `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` as administrator in either mode will help. It must be done non-interactively. Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a new account that is a member of the Administrators group. Give it a password. Use `RunAs` with that account.

Comment: What I understood from my research is that being a member of administrator group is not the same as being administrator.

Comment: In Windows Vista and later with UAC enabled, you are indeed correct. To replicate the behaviour of XP/2003 and previous, you need to turn off UAC.

Comment: OK, I already tried to run under my 'current' account that is a member of Administrators group. And it didn't solve my original issue. So now I want to make sure that I run it 100% as administrator. How do I check that UAC is enabled? Or how do I make sure that I run the command as real administrator?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think your actual problem might be somewhere else

Comment: I tried to run `tscon.exe 1 /dest:console` but it didn't help.

Comment: Not sure what is different or I didn't do it properly before but if I run `tscon.exe 1 /dest:console` as administrator I get what I need.

Comment: I had to enable the admin account in order to use `runas`. Works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Sysinternals PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) could do it?

```
psexec /s "CMD.EXE" \\computer01 -u "domain\user" -P "password"
```

After the -u, instead of `Domain\User` you can try `Computer01\LocalAdministrativeUser`

But really it depends on the local configuration of the remote machine. If you don't already have local administrator accounts on there then you are going to have to create those first.

This will launch a new CMD.EXE running as `"nt authority\system"` on the remote machine, which is as close to session 0 as you can get these days. Anything you now run in that window is running on the remote machine. Try running IPCONFIG and or HOSTNAME if you are unsure.

Careful. Running at this level allows you to really really break stuff.

Comment: Made it work using `runas`. Thank you for introducing psexec to me.